# Position of option value for Picker is out of alignment on IOS version

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

My React Native `0.61.5` app uses `Picker` from `react-native` to provide dropdown list selection. After moving to MacOS for IOS version, I notice that the position of values of dropdown selection is way below the text box out of alignment.

[image]

The value available for selection should be by the left of `Cell`.

Here is the related component code:

```
import { Dimensions, Picker, Button,TextInput,View, StyleSheet,  AppRegistry } from 'react-native'; 

      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              placeholder='Username'
              autoCapitalize="none"
              placeholderTextColor='white'
              onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText('username', val)}
            />
            <View style={styles.flexBox}> 
                <Picker.  //<<<==== Picker code
                    selectedValue={this.state.cell_country_code}
                    style={styles.inputLeft}
                    onValueChange={this.pickerValueChange}>
                    <Picker.Item label="CHINA" value="86" />
                    <Picker.Item label="USA" value="1" />
                </Picker>               
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.inputRight}
                    placeholder='Cell'
                    keyboardType='number-pad'
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    placeholderTextColor='white'
                    onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText('cell', val)}
                />
            </View>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              placeholder='Corp Name'
              autoCapitalize="none"
              placeholderTextColor='white'
              onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText('corp_name', val)}
            />
            <View style={{flexDirection:"row"}}>
              <Button
                title='Sign Up'
                onPress={this.signUp}
              />
              <Button 
                title='Enter Code'
                onPress={this.enterCode}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        )
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      input: {
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
        height: 55,
        backgroundColor: '#42A5F5',
        margin: 5,
        padding: 8,
        color: 'white',
        borderRadius: 2,
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: '500',
    },
    inputRight: {
        flex:5,
        height: 55,
        backgroundColor: '#42A5F5',
        margin: 5,
        marginRight:0,
        padding: 8,
        color: 'white',
        borderRadius: 2,
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: '500',
    },
    inputLeft: {
        flex:2,
        height: 55,
        backgroundColor: '#42A5F5',
        margin: 5,
        marginLeft:0,
        padding: 8,
        color: 'white',
        borderRadius: 2,
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: '500',
    },
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding:8,
        margin:5
    },
    flexBox: {
        flexDirection: 'row', 
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
        height: 55,
        justifyContent:"space-evenly", 
        marginBottom:10
    },
    segmentContainer: {
        marginTop:5,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    tabContainerStyle: { 
        marginTop:10,
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
        height: 55,
        backgroundColor: '#F2F2F2' 
    },
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using following code you can align your picker selection left of `Cell` in `IOS`.Set Picker style to `absolute:'position'`and`zIndex:1`.This code is also working on both platform android and IOS.

**Please check working expo code:-**

https://snack.expo.io/@vishal7008/picker-size-issue

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  Picker,
  Platform,
  Button,
  View,
  Dimensions,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    cell_country_code: 'Select code',
    isPickerVisible: false,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Username"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          placeholderTextColor="white"
          onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText('username', val)}
        />
        <View style={styles.flexBox}>
                  <View style={{ flex: 2, height: Platform.OS=='ios'?55:50,Platform.OS=='ios'?0:5, marginLeft: 5, marginRight: 5 }}>
        { Platform.OS=='ios'  &&  <TouchableOpacity
              style={{ flex: 1 }}
              onPress={() => {
                this.setState({ isPickerVisible: !this.state.isPickerVisible });
              }}>
             <TextInput
                editable={false}
                pointerEvents="none"
                style={styles.inputLeft}
                placeholder="Username"
                autoCapitalize="none"
                placeholderTextColor="white"
                value={this.state.cell_country_code}
              />

            </TouchableOpacity>
              }
            {this.state.isPickerVisible && Platform.OS=='ios' ? 
              <Picker //<<<==== Picker code
                selectedValue={this.state.cell_country_code}
                style={styles.inputLeft1}
                itemStyle={{
                  backgroundColor: '#e9e9e9',
                  color: 'black',
                  elevation: 10,
                  fontSize: 17,
                }}
                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                  this.setState({ cell_country_code: itemValue })
                }>
                <Picker.Item label="INDIA" value="+91" />
                <Picker.Item label="CHINA" value="+86" />
                <Picker.Item label="USA" value="+1" />
              </Picker>
             :Platform.OS=='android' ? <Picker //<<<==== Picker code
                selectedValue={this.state.cell_country_code}
                style={styles.inputLeftAndroid}
                itemStyle={{
                  backgroundColor: '#e9e9e9',
                  color: 'white',
                  elevation: 10,
                  fontSize: 15,
                }}
                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                  this.setState({ cell_country_code: itemValue })
                }>
                 <Picker.Item label="Select Code" value="+91" />
                <Picker.Item label="INDIA" value="+91" />
                <Picker.Item label="CHINA" value="+86" />
                <Picker.Item label="USA" value="+1" />
              </Picker>: null}
          </View>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputRight}
            placeholder="Cell"
            keyboardType="number-pad"
            autoCapitalize="none"
            placeholderTextColor="white"
            onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText('cell', val)}
          />
        </View>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Corp Name"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          placeholderTextColor="white"
          onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText('corp_name', val)}
        />
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <Button title="Sign Up" onPress={this.signUp} />
          <Button title="Enter Code" onPress={this.enterCode} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width - 10,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#42A5F5',
    margin: 5,
    padding: 8,
    color: 'white',
    borderRadius: 2,
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: '500',
  },
  inputRight: {
    flex: 5,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#42A5F5',
    marginTop: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    padding: 8,
    color: 'white',
    borderRadius: 2,
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: '500',
  },
  inputLeft: {
    flex: 3,
    height: 58,
    marginTop: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#42A5F5',
    padding: 8,
    color: 'white',
    borderRadius: 2,
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: '500',
  },
  inputLeft1: {
    flex: 0,
    height: 0.1,

  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 8,
    margin: 5,
  },
  flexBox: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: 50,
    absolute: 'position',
    zIndex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
});
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Comment: How to put the style into the `style` for the picker? The style code seems doing a few things.

Comment: The position for IOS is off somewhat. Also is there a way to make the view on both IOS & Android the same? Thanks.

Comment: We can't make same view in android and ios because of react native show native UI of picker thats why this is show different UI in android and ios. If you want to make UI in both platform you need to implement custom component or any npm please check this picker https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-modal-picker